# How to loop over a const object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a const in ReactJS which is an object and I want to loops over it to set all values to undefined to reset the state and re-render the component to get a clean form

```
const [newPayee, setNewPayee] = useState<INewPayee>(() => {
    return {
        appUserId: userInfo.id,
        fullName: '',
        phoneNumber: '',
        email: '',
        streetAddress: '',
        city: '',
        postalCode: '',
        stateId: 0,
        bankId: 0,
        bankAccountNo: '',
        bankInstitutionNo: '',
        transitNo: '',
        note: ''
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(newPayee)) {
    setNewPayee(prev => ({ ...prev, [key]: undefined }));
};
```